# How to subtract arrays by only column python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2D array

```
 [1, 5],
 [2, 7],
 [3, 9]
```

I want to result the array

```
 [1, 5],
 [2, 2],
 [3, 2]
```

which is achieved by subtracting only columns and keeping the row as its. (7-5) (9-7)

I tried this below but im not able to get the proper output

```
import numpy as np

timeline = np.array([[1,5],
                     [2,7],
                     [3,9]]) 

def non_adjacent_diff(row):
    not_zero_index = np.where(row != 0)
    diff = row[not_zero_index][1:] - row[not_zero_index][:-1]
    np.put(row, not_zero_index[0][1:], diff)
    return row

np.apply_along_axis(non_adjacent_diff, 1, timeline)

print(timeline)
```

Comment: Why is the array in your code different than the example array you start with?

Comment: How do you get from your example input 2D array to your output 2D array? Only two numbers change, but I don't see why or how they change.

Comment: Sorry i just changed the input . Yeah only 2 numbers difference the first value doesnt change [1,5],[2,(7-5)],[3,(9-7)]

Comment: i tried in different ways using numpy functions but im not able to achieve this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this solution:

```
timeline[1:,-1] = np.diff(timeline[:,-1], axis=0)
```